# Avoiding cyclic dependencies in Maven

Tags: java, maven, class

I have a project A that has project B listed as a dependency, but B does not have A as a dependency. I want to use classes from A inside B without creating a cyclic dependency. What's the best way to accomplish this without creating a new project?

A brute force approach that I thought of was to just obviously copy and paste the classes I need from A to B but this is clearly bad.

Comment: Don't do it. Anywhere you **must**, is a place where the class should have been in `B` (and you added it to `A`). Don't. Just move it from `A` to `B`. Rename it. Refactor it. Whatever. But there is no good way to use classes from `A` **in** `B`. Of course, once you've moved it from `A` to `B` you can still use it just fine in `A` (because `A` depends on `B`).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Or there should be a set of interfaces in `C` that both `A` and `B` depend on.

Comment: @chrylis-onstrike- Warning: possible crazy type talk detected.

Comment: You have an architectural problem. Separate the classes you need in B into a separate module and the problem is solved.

Answer (score 1):

> I have a project A that has project B listed as a dependency, but B does not have A as a dependency.

If A depends on B, then B cannot depend on A.

Note cyclic dependencies are problematic even if you don't use Maven.  It breaks when you start use Java 8+ modules too.  And you can run into build stability / convergence issues without using modules.

> I want to use classes from A inside B without creating a cyclic dependency.

Move the classes from B to A.  (Don't copy them.  You don't want the same class in two places.  If the fully qualified names are different you have duplicated code.  If they are the same, you could *also* run into runtime problems.)

Alternatively, create a third project C to contain the classes and have A and B depend on C.

Alternatively, combine A and B into a single project.

Alternatively, refactor the classes themselves; e.g. to introduce interfaces or abstract classes at the appropriate point, or move methods / functionality around.

In short, there are many ways to avoid a cyclic dependency between projects.  You just need to analyze your code to work out the most appropriate way (or ways) to do it.  There is no magic formula / "best practice".  Just hard work.